# Windows Phone 7 Back Key Press event change?

Tags: windows-phone-7, back-button

I want to do some work if user presses back key on the phone with navigating back How to do it?

With following code it cancel navigation to back page & do some stuff but i want to do stuff while going back please help...

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // do some stuff...

    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: if you want to go back why do you cancel the navigation, why not just remove e.Cancel = true;?

Comment: but is it going to work with (System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)

Comment: you only need to set  e.Cancel = true; when you need to cancel the back navigation

Comment: I read something about it that in this case microsoft will not certify the app

Comment: They will not certify the app if you cancel the navigation all the time not when you don't I believe

Comment: unless I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm guessing the question is what do you want to do when you go back?